# о нетипичных синонимах

Tags: синонимы

Будьте добры ответить: можно ли слово "прожить" использовать как синоним к слову "потратить", когда речь идёт о деньгах?
Как пример:
"Монархи в изгнании с завистливым восхищением сообщали друг другу, что она истратит на этот вечер больше денег, чем они могут позволить себе прожить за год."

Comment: Если ответ решил проблему - можно отметить его галочкой (под нижним серым треугольником слева от ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В словаре Кузнецова указано следующее:
4) что Издержать, израсходовать, истратить на жизнь, существование.
*Прожить все деньги, все сбережения, все средства.

Прожить всю зарплату за неделю.*
То есть при значении "*истратить всё, что было*".

Предложение нужно слегка исправить, чтобы оно стало корректным:
*Монархи в изгнании с завистливым восхищением сообщали друг другу, что она истратит **за** этот вечер больше денег, чем они могут позволить себе, **чтобы** прожить, за год.*

Answer (score 0):

Как вы понимаете, в рамках этого вполне корректного предложения слова *потратить* и *прожить* не взаимозаменяемы: нельзя "прожить за вечер" сумму денег, в то время как за год можно прожить сколько-то, если *жить* на эти деньги и *потратить* их за названный период. Следовательно, *прожить* (деньги в каком-либо размере) можно лишь за период, которым принято отмерять время *жизни*, и употребление такого глагола вместо "*потратить*" ограничено контекстом - синонимичность *условна*.

Comment: "*за год можно прожить сколько-то*" — И что, вы предлагаете это? *Они прожили 3 тысячи долларов за год.*

Comment: В вашем примере за неделю прожили.

Comment: Да, но я понимаю, что всё, что было, а не какую-то конкретную сумму. Не слышал такого.